# React Native : [Reanimated] Unknown version of Reanimated Babel plugin

Tags: react-native, babeljs, react-native-reanimated

I've had this problem for a few days now:

When I build my react native project, I get this warning :
[Reanimated] Unknown version of Reanimated Babel plugin.
See `https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/guides/troubleshooting#unknown-version-of-reanimated-babel-plugin` for more details.
Offending code was: `function anonymous(){const{worklet,args}=this.__closure;worklet(...args);}`

The consequences are that my animations don't work anymore.

Platform: iOS and android
react-native-reanimated version : 3.6.1

I tried many things to get rid of this warning:

- use --clear-cache on metro
- clear the entire workspace using react-native-clean-auto AND deleting yarn.lock file
- create a new workspace and clone again my repository
- remove recently installed libraries that use reanimated
- check and move reanimated plugin at the end of the plugins array into babel's config file
- get back to older git version of my project -> the issue is now in older versions of my project that worked in the past!

Does anyone is getting the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I changed inside package.json the version to 3.3.0

```
"dependencies": {
  ...,
  "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0", 
  ...
}
```

then i removed the yarn.lock, run `yarn install` and reinstall the iOS pods with `cd ios && pod install`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with `expo start -c`, but if you don't use expo you can try `yarn start --reset-cache` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`